# Rails 3 query multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I have an array called `@venues` with all the restaurants within a radius. Each venue `has_many`dishes and I want to insert an array of these dishes into `venue`.

```
@venues = Venue.within(radius, :origin => [lat, lng]).order('distance ASC')

@venues.each do |venue|
  dishes = venue.dishes.where("? BETWEEN DATE(served_from) AND DATE(served_until)", Date.today)
  # insert dishes into venue
end
```

How do I insert dishes into venue so that I can access all the available dishes of an venue with: `@venues[i].dishes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might might more sense to add a scope on `Dish` itself:

```
scope :today, :conditions => ["? BETWEEN DATE(served_from) AND DATE(served_until)", Date.today]
```

With that, you can access the available `dishes` with `@venues[i].dishes.today`

Comment: Agreed. It might be useful though to clarify why what they're doing is a bad idea: they're mutating the state of each Venue instance (by assigning dishes to a subset of itself) with no intent to save those changes because they're not actually correct.